# IBM SPSS TimeSeries is it possible to GroupBy

Tags: spss, spss-modeler

I need to do Sales prediction, using IBM SPSS TimeSeries module. Data grouped by Plant and Date. I need to give prediction for each Plant in dataset. In other words, model should give analysis for each Plant in source dataset. ( In SQL it is Group By statement ). Is it possible to do such analysis? Currently it give me prediction only by Date (Time) dimension. I need to include another dimension, named Plant.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good example in the example at IBM Knowledge Center ([Ref from IBM](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3RA7_17.0.0/clementine/example_broadband_forecast.html))
It's very similar to the problem that you are trying to solve. And remember to use the Time Intervals Node first in order to point out the type of group (Plant in you case).

Hope to have been helpful!